# Help using TextBox and RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, textbox, richtextbox

I'm making a menu type of all kinds of sorting algorithm. the user will input ten numbers in the TextBox, select a RadioButton, then click the generate button. the output must show each line on how the algorithm works.

(Selection Sort)

sample input from TextBox: `9 6 8 7 5 2 3 1 10 4`

output:

```
1 6 8 7 5 2 3 9 10 4 \n
1 2 8 7 5 6 3 9 10 4 \n
1 2 3 7 5 6 8 9 10 4 \n
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 10 7 \n
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 8 \n
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 9 \n
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 \n
```

I made a program like these on Java, but I only used JOptionPane. I do not have any ideas on how to convert it to c# and by using TextBox and RichTextBox.

Here's my codes so far. My output always show a lot of zeros.

```
   int[] nums = new int[10]; 
   int i, s, min, temp;

   private void EnterNum_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string[] nums = EnterNum.Text.Split(' '); 
       //int[] nums = new int[] { int.Parse(EnterNum.Text) };
   } 

   private void GenerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (SelectionRadio.Checked == true)
       {
           for (i = 0; i < nums.Length - 1; i++)
           {
               min = i; 
               // In each iteration, find the smallest number
               for (s = i + 1; s < nums.Length; s++)
               {
                   if (nums[min] > nums[s])
                   {
                       min = s;
                   }
               }
               if (min != i)
               {
                   temp = nums[i];
                   nums[i] = nums[min];
                   nums[min] = temp;
               }
               Display();
           }
       }
       Display();
   }

   private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {  
       richTextBox1.Clear();
   }

   public void Display()
   {
       int i;
       String numbers = "";
       for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         numbers += Convert.ToInt32(nums[i]).ToString() + " ";
       richTextBox1.AppendText(numbers);
   }
```

Comment: Algorithm looks correct. What's the actual output you are getting?

Comment: a lot of zeros each new line.

Comment: also why are you converting an int to Int32. Couldn't you just do nums[i].toString();?

Comment: I also tried nums[i].toString(); but has the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before starting algorithm you need to fill your `nums` array from textbox, you see zeros because by default array is filled with zeros and you just displaying default array:

```
string[] numsInString = EnterNum.Text.Split(' ');
nums = new int[numsInString.Length];
for (int j = 0; j < numsInString.Length; j++)
{
    nums[j] = int.Parse(numsInString[j]);
}  
if (SelectionRadio.Checked == true)
//...
```

and to display nicely add "\n" when appending text:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(numbers+"\n");
```

also as Matt mentioned use `.ToString()`, your `nums` are integers already so you dont need to convert `int` to `int`:

```
numbers += nums[i].ToString() + " ";
```

Comment: after looking at what you put and looking at his code again i see why he was trying to convert to an int. I think he thought that the string[] nums was what he was referencing instead of the int[] nums, and this is why i always name my variables appropriately :p.

Comment: I see. I looked again at my codes in Java, and it has a for loop statement before clicking RadioButtons. I forgot to add that on my codes here in c#. Thanks. :)